# Handling Waiting for Loading Indicators in Cypress with Mocked Backends

Tags: testing, cypress, flakyness

I have some e2e tests written with Cypress. The app uses mocked backends. The mocks are implemented using an Angular interceptor meaning the REST request will never actually leave the browser.

Now, I click on something, a loading indicator appears. I need to wait until it disappears to do further queries on elements that should be there or should not be there.

```js
cy.get('loading-indicator').should('not.exist');
cy.get('new-element).should('be.visible'); // fails when indicator was not yet shown
```

Using Cypress to wait for it to disappear results in flaky tests because the loading indicator takes to appear in the first place.

If we change it to wait for it to appear, it is also flaky as the loading indicator could already have disappeared before we start the query.

```js
cy.get('loading-indicator').should('be.visible'); // fails when indicator is already gone
cy.get('loading-indicator').should('not.exist');
cy.get('new-element).should('be.visible');
```

Now, there are a couple of solutions, explained [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/01/26/when-can-the-test-blink/) and [here](https://blog.dai.codes/cypress-loading-state-tests/).

But they all rely on intercepting an HTTP request which is not possible as explained above.

My current ugly solution is

```js
cy.wait(500);
cy.get('loading-indicator').should('not.exist');
cy.get('new-element).should('be.visible');
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It seems strange that you would get both ***indicator was not yet shown*** and ***indicator is already gone***. Please add the test details.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR As mentioned in the question. I want to assert that the indicator *was already* there and is *now gone* before I run further assertions. Due to race conditions there is no deterministic way to assert that AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

The `cy.get()` command has implied existence without need to use `.should('exist')`.

I would try the visibility test on the loading element, both positive and negative, this element may become invisible but not removed (i.e `not.exist` fails as per your test).

```js
// click on something... a loading inidicator appears

cy.get('loading-indicator').should('be.visible')
cy.get('loading-indicator').should('not.be.visible')

cy.get('new-element).should('be.visible')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The loading indicator is actually removed from the DOM when not active. So we need to do the "not.exist" check. Moreover, `cy.get('loading-indicator').should('be.visible')` would fail when the loading indicator has already disappeared before the Cypress command is executed. I tried this already.

Comment: Sounds like it is an invalid assumption - Javascript is single threaded, you will only get a race condition if you use `cy.wait()` to give up the thread.

Answer (score 4):

Since the backend calls are mocked, I suggest switch to Cypress `intercept` and add delay to give the loader time to be caught.

Using a `middleware` option applies the delay to all other intercepts.

```js
  cy.intercept({
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/**',
      middleware: true,
    },
    (req) => {
      req.on('response', (res) => {
        res.setDelay(2000)
      })
    }
  )
```

It is also required to check for positive existence first, as negative timeout with `.should('not.exist')` does not wait the 4 seconds timeout - you *must* check that an element exists before checking that it does not exist.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But as I pointed out, intercepting does not work as the requests are intercepted and mocked by the UI framework, so there is nothing to intercept. I actually tried it before just to realize that nothing ever get's intercepted.

Comment: Yes, intercept will not work in that case - you should *switch* as I pointed out.